# How to Pause the Shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script that ends with `exit 0` and want to pause it before executing the command.

Comment: Replace `exit 0` with `read; exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

To pause for 3 seconds,

```
sleep 3
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for `read -p "Press [Enter] ..."`

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in your shell script before the line in your shell script that executes the command.

```
echo "Press any key to continue."
while [ true ] ; do
read -t 10 -n 1  
echo ""
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
exit;
else
echo "Waiting for a keypress..."
fi
done
```

The code waits 10 seconds for a the user press any key and then prompts the user again to press any key to continue. If three seconds is too long to wait then change the `10` in the line that says `read -t 10 -n 1` to a smaller number.

<sub>**source:** revised from [Bash wait for keypress](https://linuxhint.com/bash_wait_keypress/)</sub>